# Including scheduler module in react application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, module, scheduler

Im new to react and just getting the grips with hooks and function based components. Im trying to incorporate a react scheduler into my react application but with no luck. The scheduler I want to use is under this repo, and it is based on class based components;

https://github.com/hiramzamorano/react-big-scheduler

I created a react application and added the module, which i can see in the package.json file under dependencies

`create-react-app test_react`

`npm install scheduler-react --save`

I got rid of all unnecessary files and my application folder has only

- index.js
- app.js
- app.css
- a_basic.js
- a_basic.css

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';


ReactDOM.render(
      <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**app.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import a_basic from './a_basic';

import './App.css';


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <a_basic/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**app.css**

```
body, #root, .App {
    /* background-color: cadetblue; */
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    font-family: monospace;
    /* border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 20px;  */
}
```

**a_basic.js**

```
import React from 'react'

import Scheduler, {SchedulerData, ViewTypes, DATE_FORMAT} from 'scheduler-react'

import 'scheduler-react/lib/css/style.css'
import moment from 'moment'

import './a_basic.css'


function a_basic() {

    let schedulerData = new SchedulerData(new moment().format(DATE_FORMAT), ViewTypes.Week);
    //set locale moment to the schedulerData, if your locale isn't English. By default, Scheduler comes with English(en, United States).
    moment.locale('zh-cn');
    schedulerData.setLocaleMoment(moment);
    //set resources here or later
    let resources = [
                            {
                    id: 'r0',
                    name: 'Resource0',
                    author: "X",
                    bgColor: 'red',
                    issue: '#1'
                },
                {
                    id: 'r1',
                    name: 'Resource1',
                    author: "X",
                    bgColor: '#D9D9D9',
                    issue: '#2'
                },
                {
                    id: 'r2',
                    name: 'Resource2',
                    author: "X",
                    issue: '#99'
                },
                    ];
    schedulerData.setResources(resources);
    //set events here or later,
    //the event array should be sorted in ascending order by event.start property, otherwise there will be some rendering errors
    let events = [
                    {
                        id: 1,
                        start: '2017-12-18 09:30:00',
                        end: '2017-12-19 23:30:00',
                        resourceId: 'r1',
                        title: 'I am finished',
                        label: 'QA Failed',
                        img: 'https://miro.medium.com/fit/c/28/28/1*UJzclN5h-DYWjRyVqXThUw.png',
                        bgColor: '#D9D9D9',
                        showPopover: false
                    },
                    {
                        id: 2,
                        start: '2017-12-18 12:30:00',
                        end: '2017-12-26 23:30:00',
                        resourceId: 'r2',
                        title: 'I am not resizable',
                        label: 'Development',
                        resizable: false
                    },
                    {
                        id: 3,
                        start: '2017-12-19 12:30:00',
                        end: '2017-12-20 23:30:00',
                        resourceId: 'r3',
                        title: 'I am not movable',
                        movable: false
                    },
                    {
                        id: 4,
                        start: '2017-12-19 14:30:00',
                        end: '2017-12-20 23:30:00',
                        resourceId: 'r1',
                        title: 'I am not start-resizable',
                        startResizable: false
                    },
                    {
                        id: 5,
                        start: '2017-12-19 15:30:00',
                        end: '2017-12-20 23:30:00',
                        resourceId: 'r2',
                        title: 'R2 has recurring tasks every week on Tuesday, Friday',
                        rrule: 'FREQ=WEEKLY;DTSTART=20171219T013000Z;BYDAY=TU,FR',
                        bgColor: '#f759ab'
                    }
                ];
    schedulerData.setEvents(events);



    return (
        <div id ="base">
            <Scheduler 
                schedulerData={schedulerData}
                // prevClick={prevClick}
                // nextClick={nextClick}
                // onSelectDate={onSelectDate}
                // onViewChange={onViewChange}
                // eventItemClick={eventClicked}
            />
            
        </div>
    )
}

export default a_basic
```

**a_basic.css**

```
#base {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Im not seeing anything in the browser when i run the project. Im sure that im doing something wrong, but i dont know what it is. Please dont mind the component name **a_basic**. At this point im just experimenting with module inclusion

How can I include this scheduler in my application using the functional components method?

EDIT: I have changed the name from **a_basic.js** to **BasicScheduler.js** in order to avoid accidental rendering. But now im experiencing some "drag drop context" related errors

**TypeError: createBackend is not a function**

Still unable to get the application working

Comment: what do you see in the DOM? My suspicion is in fact the name of the component **a_basic**: components in react MUST begin with an uppercase letter, otherwise it will try to render a `<a_basic>` html element which does not exist. Try importing it as `A_basic` and referencing in your render method as `<A_basic`

Comment: I have changed the name to BasicScheduler to avoid any accidental rendering. Now im receiving this error:

Could not find the drag and drop manager in the context of ResourceEvents. Make sure to wrap the top-level component of your app with DragDropContext. Read more: http://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/docs/troubleshooting#could-not-find-the-drag-and-drop-manager-in-the-context

Comment: That seems completely unrelated to any code you have - I think it's an issue with `react-big-scheduler`: https://github.com/StephenChou1017/react-big-scheduler/issues/215 - Note that the `scheduler-react` package you are using is a fork of `react-big-scheduler`: https://github.com/hiramzamorano/react-big-scheduler. Welcome to Open Source and npm packages :)

Answer (score 0):

I have used this library in my project and its working very well.

I think there is a version issue in your case and I would suggest you to use **"react-big-scheduler": "^0.2.7"**,

You can try - `npm install react-big-scheduler@0.2.7`

And one more thing..., please **do not install DnD module** because it is deprecated and won't work now. So just try without it.

I hope this suggestion will help you.